# Move a valid Windows 8.1 license to a valid Windows 7 machine?

Tags: windows-7, windows-8, system-restore, windows-media-center

I have two computers.

One is an older computer has been running Windows 7 Home with Media Center for years.  But now there are issues with Media Center on that computer.  Also, this computer no longer has valid DVD drive (probably not important.)

I have a second newer computer with dual boot on two partitions.  Both partitions have with Windows 8.1 Pro with Media Center. Call them Partition A and Partition B.  But I only use one of them.  So I have three valid windows licenses. (One Windows 7 and two Windows 8.1).  Both computers are 64-bit.

I can't go to Windows 10 because it doesn't support Media Center.

I am fine with being done with Windows 7 OS on the old computer.  I would like to know if there is a way to "move" the Windows 8.1 Partition B to the old computer.

I can create a System Image of Partition B.  But I am not clear on how to run the restore on the old Windows 7 computer.   (Seems like I would somehow need to upgrade it to Windows 8.1 just to allow it to do a restore??)

**Any ideas on how to move my valid Windows 8.1 Pro with Media Center license to a different computer that currently has Windows 7?**

Comment: Moving to new hardware will cause the Windows licence to de-activate, something you should consider.

Comment: But I thought you could do a phone activation.

Comment: If it is oem Windows they will not activate it on different hardware.

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/985211/how-do-i-tell-if-a-windows-8-1-product-keys-is-an-oem-key

Comment: My Windows 8.1 is a retail license version.

Comment: There is no migration from Windows 7 to Windows 8.1.  So if you want to keep everything that isn't possible without first going to Windows 8.  Windows 8.1 keys cannot be used to activate or install Windows 8.0.  You would need to format the computer with Windows 8.1 and then install it on the machine with Windows 7.  Once you can activate WIndows 8.1 on the machine your transferring it to.

Comment: Ramhound's information is incorrect. You **can** directly upgrade from Windows 7 to Windows 8.1 and keep everything. You do not need to reformat it.

Comment: @qasdfdsaq: I'm concerned about your repeatedly telling Ramhound that he's incorrect. If you have a grievance with him, please come to [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/118/root-access) and discuss it with us. Thanks.

Comment: @DragonLord: I have no grievance. He is just tends to be repeatedly incorrect. I have a problem with misleading information being posted and I tell anyone who posts incorrect information that it is incorrect.

Comment: @qasdfdsaq it does seem a little like you're following him around to do it.  I've noticed a few cases where this has happened. If you must, post an answer.

Comment: [I still maintain the only way to upgrade from Windows 7 to Windows 8.1 is if you are willing to lose your installed applications, and application settings (i.e. you don't keep everything) which I attempted to indicate was the case in my original comment.](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-sg/windows-8/upgrade-from-windows-7-tutorial).  I admit I could have phrased my comment better though.

Answer (score 2):

From the information I've gathered you may need to use phone activation, but according to the EULA you are allowed to transfer a retail license.

Do a clean install using your retail license. Restoring an image to different hardware causes way to many headaches.

*There's a great - somewhat dated - [blog post](http://blog.superuser.com/2011/04/06/microsoft-licencing-transferring-windows-to-another-computer/) on superuser about Windows 7 OEM vs Retail activation.*

### **OEM**

Cannot be transferred to another machine.

### Retail

Retail copies can only be installed on one computer at a time. You will have to remove the software from your current machine.

**Windows 8 EULA:** [[PDF]](http://download.microsoft.com/Documents/UseTerms/Windows_8_English_ca383862-45cf-467e-97d3-386e0e0260a6.pdf)

> **Can I transfer the software to another computer or user?**
>
> You may transfer the software to another computer that belongs to you. You may also transfer the software (together with the license) to a computer owned by someone else if a) you are the first licensed user of the software and b) the new user agrees to the terms of this agreement. To make that transfer, you must transfer the original media, the certificate of authenticity, the product key and the proof of purchase directly to that other person, without retaining any copies of the software. You may use the backup copy we allow you to make or the media that the software came on to transfer the software. Anytime you transfer the software to a new  computer, you must remove the software from the prior computer. You may not transfer the software to share licenses between computers. You may transfer Get Genuine Windows software, Pro Pack or Media Center Pack software only together with the licensed computer.

Answer (score 1):

Transforming the physical disk into a partition on another computer can be
extremely complicated. You may have to face problems with incompatible hardware,
incompatible BIOS - UEFI or legacy, incorrect partition identifier stamped in the
registry of Windows 8.1, reactivation of Windows etc. etc. etc.

In my opinion, the best course of action is to convert the Windows 8.1 computer
into a virtual machine and run it that way on the Windows 7 computer.
Dual-booting the two is just too complicated to do.

You can use [VMware vCenter Converter](https://my.vmware.com/web/vmware/evalcenter?p=converter&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&gws_rd=cr&ei=PgMhVoXWBsGza-O9psgB) to convert the physical computer
to a VMware virtual machine (P2V), then use [VMware Player](https://my.vmware.com/web/vmware/free#desktop_end_user_computing/vmware_workstation_player/12_0)
to run the resulting virtual machine.

The process is explained in this [VMware Knowledge Base article](http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=2005129).
From my experience, this also avoids the need for reactivating Windows.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft confirms that you can update [windows 7 to 8.1](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-sg/windows-8/upgrade-from-windows-7-tutorial). That said I distinctly remember I had two sets of keys, one to install 8.1 and one for media center. Just pop in your windows 8.1 media, run through the install process and it should work. Assuming you have a 8.1 MCE upgrade key, you *may* have to use the 8.1 key and then the windows 7 key.

As with any upgrade things my go horribly wrong, and a backup is always a great idea.