# How do I tell if a Windows 8.1 Product Keys is an OEM key?

Tags: windows-8.1, authentication, license, oem, product-key

My system has been upgraded multiple times.  Latest was upgraded to Windows 8.1 Pro with media center.  I would like to move the license.  But I am not sure if I have still have an OEM Licensed Product Key (Product Id).

Is there a way to tell?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Open a command prompt and enter the command:

```
slmgr.vbs /dli
```

Next to the name of the operating system it will tell you a "channel". There is no single one for OEM licenses but afaik all of those that are OEM also start with OEM. In contrast the most common non OEM license would probably be "RETAIL Channel".