# OEM Windows 7 product key missing 1 letter, how can I fill in the blank?

Tags: windows-7, product-key, recovery, validation

I have a Lenovo ThinkCentre machine I'm trying to refurbish for a friend. I'd like to install the version of Windows it came with, but the Microsoft OEM key sticker is missing one letter near the very end (00000-X0000). I'd like to just plug away and try the [24 possible characters](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/why-is-the-character-o-not-valid-with-a-microsoft/4c06b433-98ed-4c9d-a860-c7399a0e3e3e), but that Microsoft PID checker didn't work using Windows 7 Embedded or the Windows 7 / Server 2008 drop down.

I ran Magic Jelly Bean and got a CD key that was very different than the one on the machine's side. I think it was a corporate key (this machine belonged to a company before). I'd rather not use that as it's probably a pro/enterprise key. What's the best way to validate/recover the Windows 7 key?

Comment: You might want to try this: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows7  If you can download the ISO then your license is good. This was the answer to this: https://superuser.com/questions/1105882/determine-if-windows-7-product-key-is-oem-before-installation?rq=1

Comment: I had tried that but 2 things
1. Microsoft was taking between 20 seconds and 2 minutes to "verify" before saying "Error We encountered a problem with the validation request." - no pass/fail
2. It's unclear after how many tries microsoft might just stop trying to validate and throw up that error to prevent brute forcing.

Comment: The original OEM key may still be burnt into the BIOS. Try [these methods](https://www.thewindowsclub.com/find-windows-product-key).

Comment: @Jeff I've just tested it using a laptop key and it works. It did give an error but the error confirms its valid: its saying me the key is OEM. https://i.imgur.com/KoDd60e.png

Comment: you can use this tool to automatically install necessary license certificates. [WindowsLoader](http://www.mediafire.com/file/p3hhzt72qwx8gaq/Windows_Loader.zip/file)